# My girlfriend is going to be a public servant. Is it worth to marry now?

Tags: income-tax, germany

My girlfriend and I, have been together for 4 years now. I'm pretty sure she is the one.
I'm thinking about asking her to marry me, but don't know if I should do it now, or later.
I surely will ask her, the question is just about the timing.

At the moment, she studies lectureship and due a lack of teachers in the position she is studying for, she is probably going to be a public servant. She will finish her studies  in about 2 years, maybe a bit longer.

At the moment, her income is very low, since she is a student. By herself she would barely be able to pay rent, fill the fridge, and so on.
On my side, my salary isn't high, but is good enough to (theoretically) feed us both, maintain 2 cars (which we need) and all other necessities. No big luxuries, but it covers our basic needs plus a little extra.

If she is getting a civil servant's salary, our income will be roughly the same (around 3000€ gross) which would allow us to live a good life without any existential fear.

My question now is, is it worth to marry her **now**, or should I wait until she got her degree (of course for financial reasons alone).

Her income now is between 400 and 600€ from 3(!) part time jobs, while mine is 2700€ gross.

Which tax category would we be in if we marry now?
After her graduation the question will be 4/4, 3/5 or 5/3, that's pretty clear. But what would it be now?

Comment: Dude, first get a tax advisor. Don't use the tax criteria to decide when to marry, unless there is an incentive somewhere(pay less tax if not married).

Comment: That's the point of my question. I don't know if I would pay more or less tax if married in this constellation.

Comment: Check here http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Taxation_in_Germany#Income_tax_for_residents. `class III = married and spouse has no income or lower income`. Isn't there the German tax authority website which you can use ? Currently you are paying tax independent of each other.

Comment: I can't tell you what the tax implications will be, but who cares? Marry her now! Life is short and you found the one!

Comment: What is the opportunity cost of losing a bride? I think you need to factor that in.

Comment: @JohnFx Depends on whether she has life insurance. :)

Comment: @dg99 It also depends on who is the beneficiary! ;-)

Comment: if you would use the basic "Ehegattensplitting" you would have lower taxes. It means you add both your incomes and divide it by two, and that is the new gross of both partners. IF you use basic tax calculators, you can see that the income after deductions will be higher for two 1650 incomes, than for one 2700 and one 600. (but it is not super much). Maybe this could be even better if she would have and income below 450 (taxfree), but im not sure how exactly this works in this kind of scenario. Better ask a tax advisor.

Comment: Is she going to be *your* servant?

Comment: Why not get engaged first and then work with your fiance on deciding an appropriate wedding date? This is the sort of decision you want your significant other to weigh in on.